# How to iterate through structured regex searches?

Tags: javascript, office-scripts

I'm new to JavaScript and have managed to cobble together something that works but I'd like to improve on it for better efficiency and ease of future maintenance.

The code is used in an office-script and is looking for several specific structured values in an OCR data output and returning the values if found and a placeholder if not found. This is so the output array can be parsed in power automate.

I'd like to just have an array of regex patterns to add or remove from and the result is an array of the patterns in the order of the array with a value if not found. This is so nulls don't affect my result array order.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, inputString: string,): Array<string> {

    let GST: Array<string> = inputString.match(RegExp(/(?<![0-9])([0-9]{2,3})[- ]([0-9]{3})[- ]([0-9]{3})(?![0-9])/g));
    let NZD: Array<string> = inputString.match(RegExp(/[Nn][Zz][Dd]/g));
    let POnum: Array<string> = inputString.match(RegExp(/([aA-zZ]{1,3})-([0-9]{6})-([0-9]{3})(?![0-9])/g));
    let BAN: Array<string> = inputString.match(RegExp(/(?<![0-9])([0-9]{2})[- ]([0-9]{4})[- ]([0-9]{7})[- ]([0-9]{2,3})(?![0-9])/g));
    if (GST === null) { var Gstvalue = "no match" }  else { Gstvalue = GST[0] };
    if (NZD === null) { var Nzdvalue = "no match" } else { Nzdvalue = NZD[0] };
    if (POnum === null) { var POnumvalue = "no match" } else { POnumvalue = POnum[0] };
    if (BAN === null) { var BANvalue = "no match" } else { BANvalue = BAN[0] };
    var map = new Map();
    map.set('GST',Gstvalue );
    map.set('NZD',Nzdvalue);
    map.set('POnum', POnumvalue);
    map.set('BAN', BANvalue);



return [map.get('GST'), map.get('NZD'), map.get('POnum'), map.get('BAN')]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could greatly be reduced to an array of regular expressions and mapping over them:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, inputString: string): Array<string> {
    const regex = [
        /(?<![0-9])([0-9]{2,3})[- ]([0-9]{3})[- ]([0-9]{3})(?![0-9])/g,
        /[Nn][Zz][Dd]/g,
        /([aA-zZ]{1,3})-([0-9]{6})-([0-9]{3})(?![0-9])/g,
        /(?<![0-9])([0-9]{2})[- ]([0-9]{4})[- ]([0-9]{7})[- ]([0-9]{2,3})(?![0-9])/g,
    ];

    // for each pattern we have
    return regex.map((re) => {
        // matches for this particular regex
        const match = inputString.match(re);
        // no match
        if (match === null) return "no match";
        // first match
        return match[0];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I was after.